# concatenate all properties of 2 similar objects javaScript

Tags: javascript, iteration, concatenation

I have 2 different objects, with the same properties which i want to concatenate:

```
obj1 = {id: "1: identifier 1 \n", description: "1: description 1 \n", ...., propertyX1}
obj2 = {id: "2: identifier 2 \n", description: "2: description 2 \n", ...., propertyX2}
```

My result should be:

```
obj1 = {id: "1: identifier 1 \n 2: identifier 2 \n", 
          description: "1: description 1 \n 2: description 2", 
          ...., 
          propertyX1|propertyX2}
```

My solution so far is:

```
function combineElements(element1, element2){
    var property1, property2;
    for (property1 in element1) {
        if(element1.hasOwnProperty(property1)) {//bonus question: why does intellij ask me to add this?
            property2 = element2.getSameProperty(property1); // <<<<<<how do I iterate this?
            property1 = "\n" + property2;
        }
    }
    return element1;
}
```

How would you get the exact same property of the second element?

Comment: `element2[property1]`

Comment: whart do you want with `propertyX1` and `propertyX2`?

Comment: used ..., propertyX1 to denote that you don't really know hoe long the list of properties is. You just want to concat all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concat all properties with the same name.

Techniques use (in order of apperance):

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), like `{ [k]: value }` (`k` is the name of the property)
- [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) for taking a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value

```js
var obj1 = { id: "1: identifier 1 \n", description: "1: description 1 \n", propertyX1: 'propertyX1' },
    obj2 = { id: "2: identifier 2 \n", description: "2: description 2 \n", propertyX2: 'propertyX2' },
    result = [obj1, obj2].reduce(
        (r, o) => Object.assign(r, ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: (r[k] || '') + v }))),
        {}
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't think making dense one liners is the way to go with someone not knowing how to access a property.

Comment: @destoryer, right, that might be the problem, but i try to write the best possible answer. it might have a higher degree of knowing what part is doing, but op is free to ask, and anybody her can answer or edit this question.

Comment: Works! But as above comment says i dont really understand how. I would like to learn how to do the above :) any tips on keywords to google for to start to learning this?

Answer (score 2):

```
function combineElements(element1, element2) {
   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element1).forEach(function(k1) {
       if (element2[k1]) {
         element1[k1] = element1[k1] + " " + element2[k1];
       }
   });
}
```

find the matching keys for the 2 objects

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse one of the objects and make a new one like that.

```js
obj1 = {id: "1: identifier 1 \n", description: "1: description 1 \n"}
obj2 = {id: "2: identifier 2 \n", description: "2: description 2 \n"}

conObj = {};

for (var prop in obj1){
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         conObj[prop] = obj1[prop] + obj2[prop];
    }
}

console.log(conObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to hold the individual keys and iterate using [Set.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) and [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate the values.

```js
var obj1 = {id: "1: identifier 1 \n", description: "1: description 1 \n", propertyX1:"propertyX1", propertyX3:"propertyX3"};
var obj2 = {id: "2: identifier 2 \n", description: "2: description 2 \n", propertyX2:"propertyX2", propertyX4:"propertyX4"};

var keys = new Set(Object.keys(obj1).concat(Object.keys(obj2)));

var result={};

keys.forEach(function(key){
    result[key] = [obj1[key], obj2[key]].join(" ");
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be [Set.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach)?